# How can I replace a specific character in a file where it's position changes in bash command line or script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have the following file:

> 2020-01-27 19:43:57.00 C M -8.5   0.2   0       4      81  -2.9   000 0 0 00020 043857.82219 ***3*** 1 1 1 1 1

The character "3" that I need to change is **bolded** and *italicized*.  The value of this character is dynamic, but always a single digit.  I have tried a few things using sed but I can't come up with a way to account for the character changing position due to additional characters being added before that position.

This character is always at the same position from the END of the line, but not from the beginning.  Meaning, the content to the left of this character may change and it may be longer, but this is always the 11th character and 6th digit from the end.  It is easy to devise a way to cut it, or find it using tail, but I can't devise a way to replace it.

To be clear, the single digit character in question will always be replaced with another single digit character.

Comment: Please specify the criteria for the character that must be changed.  What precisely is meant by the "same position from the END of the line"?  Would a solution using (e.g.) awk be acceptable?

Comment: The question title says 'replace', but the question body gives no indication of what the digit in the sixth from final column needs to be replaced with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk

```sh
$ cat file
2020-01-27 19:43:57.00 C M -8.5 0.2 0 4 81 -2.9 000 0 0 00020 043857.82219 3 1 1 1 1 1

$ gawk -i inplace -v new=9 'NF {$(NF-5) = new} 1' file

$ cat file
2020-01-27 19:43:57.00 C M -8.5 0.2 0 4 81 -2.9 000 0 0 00020 043857.82219 9 1 1 1 1 1
```

Where:

- `NF {$(NF-5) = new}` means, when the line is not empty, replace the 6th-last field with the new value (9).
- `1` means print every record.

Comment: This worked perfectly, will work even if that character changes, and this answer was the easiest to understand.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ $(NF-5) = ($(NF - 5) + 8) % 10; print }'
```

Given your input data, it produces;

```
2020-01-27 19:43:57.00 C M -8.5 0.2 0 4 81 -2.9 000 0 0 00020 043857.82219 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The 3 has been mapped via 11 to 1 — pick your poison on how you assign the new value, but the magic is `$(NF - 5)` to pick up the fifth column before the last one (or sixth from end).

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume that the number that you're looking for is the same distance from the end, regardless of what comes before it:

```
rev ~/test.txt | awk '$6=<value to replace>' | rev
```

Comment: Your code correctly isolates the sixth-from-final column.  Your code doesn't self-evidently provide a way of changing that column into a different value, leaving the rest unchanged.

Comment: ah dang, true that

Comment: It's a more or less sensible continuation of your original idea, but using `rev` twice is a bit convoluted when a single invocation of Awk could do the whole job.

Comment: ya, def could be done with a single command but ive found that teasing out what that command does months or years later are hard for myself or other devs to tease apart which is why i prefer the composition aproach 

Answer (score 0):

Would you try the following:

```
replace="x"     # or whatever you want to replace
sed 's/\(.\)\(.\{10\}\)$/'"$replace"'\2/' file
```

- The left portion of the sed command `\(.\)\(.\{10\}\)$` matches a character, followed by ten characters, then anchored by the end of line.
- Then the 1st character is replaced with the specified character and the following ten characters are reused.

Answer (score 0):

Using the bash shell which should be the last option.

```
rep=10

read -ra var <<< '2020-01-27 19:43:57.00 C M -8.5 0.2 0 4 81 -2.9 000 0 0 00020 043857.82219 3 1 1 1 1 1'
for i in "${!var[@]}"; do printf '%s ' "${var[$i]/${var[-6]}/$rep}"; done
```

If it is in a file.

```
rep=10
read -ra var < file.txt

for i in "${!var[@]}"; do printf '%s ' "${var[$i]/${var[-6]}/$rep}"; done
```

Not the shortest and fastest way but it can be done...